# How to get jQuery to submit a form to a post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I am validating with jQuery.

```
<form id="target" class="center-block" action="/" method="POST">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="name" rows="3" name="name" placeholder="Enter a burger you would like to devour!"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="center-block btn btn-default top">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After validation I am also trying to submit the form via jQuery.

```
if (validateForm() == true) {
   $("#target").submit();
}
```

The validation is working however, it doesn't seem like the form is submitting to the post route.  I was able to get the form to post using ajax, but the post wouldn't redirect after finishing.  Was hoping this method would give the desired effect.

The app is running on Express and using MySQL.

Comment: Via Ajax or not?

Comment: What is the "desired effect" you're looking for? If you're submitting to the same page take the / out of action.

Comment: If the validition works, and the page redirects, it works. There's nothing more anyone else can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your jquery `submit` will work ,because an element `id or name submit` will replace the `form.submit` method, you should simply change id (name also shouldn't give that).

```
<button type="button" id="changeThisId" class="center-block btn btn-default top">Submit</button>
```

Comment: And now I feel stupid since it also says that in the documentation in the additional notes.  [https://api.jquery.com/submit/](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax` and if you want to redirect to the current page, on success reload the current page

```
$.ajax({    
    url: yourUrl,
    type: "post",
    data: $("#target").serialize(),
    success: function(r){
        //form posted successfully
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function(error){
      alert(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have a typo in there, but the idea is:

```
$('#target').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: { ... },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $.ajax{
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url: '/',
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```